# I really need to know the steps - how to insert my own html template into umbraco?

Tags: templates, umbraco

I really need to know the steps - how to insert my own html template into umbraco?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between 'html templates' and macro's.

You're looking at the overview of macro's. At the bottom left, you should click 'settings' and then open the item 'Masterpages'. That is where the basic Masterpage is to be put - that is the general layout of the website.

Macro's are pieces of script you can put in a page to generate a menu, or a list of the latest news items. You can even write plain .NET user controls and use them just like you use a Macro. A macro can exist of a XSLT-file, or a script file (Razor-script) or use a UserControl.

I suppose you should read a good tutorial first. This one seemed pretty good: http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2010/5/13/building-your-first-umbraco-site-from-scratch